# Azure Speech To Text cURL call fail

Tags: azure, speech-recognition

I am following the troubleshootin guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/troubleshooting).

I have obtained the access token as follows:

```sh
curl -v -X POST \
 "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" \
 -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
 -H "Content-Length: 0" \
 -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY"
```

(I replaced `YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY` with my key and I got a long access token).

I tried to call the STT service with the following cURL call:

```sh
curl -v -X POST \
 "https://westus.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US" \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
 -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" \
 -H "Content-type: audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000" \
 --data-binary ./whatstheweatherlike.wav
```

(I replaced YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN with my long access token).

I am using the sample file from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/387#issuecomment-536598326).

I get the following error: `{"Message":"Unsupported audio format"}`.

What's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of your audio file? Mp3 or any other?

Comment: @ChamilaMaddumage: Actually solved the problem. The input path for WAV file needed a `@` in front. Thanks!

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni Cheers! Would you please summarize your solution as an answer for others' reference? Thank you!

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni Don't forget mark yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody who replied in the comments.

I guess, I was missing a `@` character while specifying the audio file.

So, I changed

```sh
--data-binary ./whatstheweatherlike.wav
```

to

```sh
--data-binary @./whatstheweatherlike.wav
```

and it worked!